# Does uninstalling pip remove all its packages?

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation

If I uninstall pip with

```
pip uninstall pip
```

does it remove all installed packages too?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `pip` is a tool that handles downloading packages and installing them to various locations; those locations are not part of `pip`'s own install directories. As such, removing `pip` has no effect on installed packages.

(Common paths for installing packages include `/usr/lib/<pythonversion>` or `/usr/local/lib/<pythonversion>`.)

Comment: Thanks Amber! can I clean up the packages by reinstalling pip, removing packages, and then uninstalling again, or are they now orphaned forever? (I accidentally ran curl -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-cli-resources/install-ebcli.py | python)

Comment: Reinstalling pip should allow you to do anything that having pip installed before could do.